# Clickable Links in Revision Comments

Tags: script, revisions, hyperlinks

### Description:

This is a really simple userscript that [turns URLs in revision history comments into clickable links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288954/230261):

[image]

### Features:

- Works in both revision list and single revision links.

### Download:

- [Github](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/RevisionCommentLinks.user.js)
- [Github raw](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/raw/master/RevisionCommentLinks.user.js)

### Notes:

- Based off [this link replacer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7123542/616460), which seems to be good enough so far.

### Change Log:

- [1.01](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/359ae7debfc9825ee7c7e7f646f1202133a09185)

  - Fixed some broken match filters.
- [1.00](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/7c81854ac3713f218d31cff99b58908b335acee5)

  - Initial version.

---

[Check out my other scripts.](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a25350%20is%3aq%20%5bscript%5d%20)